# Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite 6.3 - DataInputSet and DataOutputSet fields are missing in business rule task

Tags: jbpm

I am new to JBPM. Now I am testing Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite 6.3 and I deployed business-central application on weblogic.

I met a problem by following the online guide. In my process designer, DataInputSet and DataOutputSet fields are missing in the core properties of business rule task.

Below is the screenshot of core properties with DataInputSet and DataOutputSet fields:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIIdr.png

Below is my process designer where the two fields are missing:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfIfn.png

I checked online to see if this is caused by different version of redhat jbpm suite, but it may not be the case, cause the latest doc on redhat website indicates that the two fields should be there. And there is no other useful info. I can find by googling.
Has anyone met this problem before? Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem after hours of triage.
It turned out that the fields called DataInputSet, DataOutputSet and Assignments mentioned in development guide are combined to one field called Assigments.

And you may need to define a variable in BPMN-Diagram to finish the mapping:
Properties(BPMN-Diagram) 
Core properties - Variable Definition

Comment: For more info, check https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_BPM_Suite/6.3/html/User_Guide/sect_assignment.html